# Loop redirect with '/' in nginx proxying Gitlab CE in Omnibus package

Tags: redirect, nginx, gitlab-omnibus

I'm configuring a non-bundled nginx server for the Gitlab-Omnibus instance with (1) redirection of HTTP traffic to HTTPS and (2) self-signed certificate.

I am permanently getting loop redirect with the root location.

Here is what curl writes:

```
F:\tmp>curl.exe -I -L https://localsite.example.com
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.10.2
Date: Mon, 06 Feb 2017 14:47:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Location: http://localsite.example.com
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id: 889bcd5a-0646-46c1-902a-e569833a3b0d
X-Runtime: 0.032797
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 06 Feb 2017 14:47:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://localsite.example.com/

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.10.2
Date: Mon, 06 Feb 2017 14:47:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Location: http://localsite.example.com
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id: 9be22e5f-07f3-4381-a161-109960cb5338
X-Runtime: 0.039810
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 06 Feb 2017 14:47:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://localsite.example.com/

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.10.2
Date: Mon, 06 Feb 2017 14:47:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Location: http://localsite.example.com
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id: 14f4de36-d327-467a-b3c2-716f11ec5499
X-Runtime: 0.059843
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
....

curl: (47) Maximum (50) redirects followed
```

I've taken a recipe from [here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/web-server/nginx/gitlab-omnibus-ssl-nginx.conf) and here is the relevant part of my nginx.conf

```
upstream gitlab-workhorse {
  server unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
     listen 0.0.0.0:80;
     server_name localsite.example.com;
     server_tokens off; ## Don't show the nginx version number, a security best practice
     return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri; 
 }

 server {
     listen 443 ssl default;
     server_name localsite.example.com;
     ssl on;

     ssl_certificate /etc/gitlab/ssl/localsite.example.com.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/gitlab/ssl/localsite.example.com.key;

     ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
     ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
     ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
     ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
     ssl_session_timeout 5m;

     root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;

     location / {
         root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;
         client_max_body_size 0;
         gzip off;

         ## https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
         ## Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
         proxy_read_timeout      300;
         proxy_connect_timeout   300;
         proxy_redirect      off;

         proxy_http_version 1.1;

         proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
         proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Ssl     on;
         proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   https;

         proxy_pass          http://gitlab-workhorse;
     }
}
```

Ubuntu 14.04, nginx 1.10.2, installed from PPA.

Other locations don't receive loop redirect. For example, `curl.exe -I -L http://localsite.example.com/public`, returns 301, then 200.

So, what is wrong?

*Update after reading the comment*

Yes, this is gitlab-workhorse, that returns `Location: http://localsite.example.com`. According to docs, it cannot run https.
This is what I've got in logs after enabling debug

```
2017/02/07 11:30:41 [debug] 31020#31020: *26471 http proxy header: "User-Agent: curl/7.49.0"
2017/02/07 11:30:41 [debug] 31020#31020: *26471 http proxy header: "Accept: */*"
2017/02/07 11:30:41 [debug] 31020#31020: *26471 http proxy header:
"HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: localsite.example.com
X-Real-IP: 192.168.129.34
X-Forwarded-Ssl: on
X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.129.34
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
Connection: close
User-Agent: curl/7.49.0
Accept: */*

"
2017/02/07 11:30:41 [debug] 31020#31020: *26471 connect to unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket, fd:16 #26472
2017/02/07 11:30:41 [debug] 31020#31020: *26471 connected
2017/02/07 11:30:41 [debug] 31020#31020: *26471 http upstream connect: 0

2017/02/07 11:30:41 [debug] 31020#31020: *26471 http proxy status 302 "302 Found"
2017/02/07 11:30:41 [debug] 31020#31020: *26471 http proxy header: "Cache-Control: no-cache"
2017/02/07 11:30:41 [debug] 31020#31020: *26471 http proxy header: "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"
2017/02/07 11:30:41 [debug] 31020#31020: *26471 http proxy header: "Date: Tue, 07 Feb 2017 08:30:41 GMT"
2017/02/07 11:30:41 [debug] 31020#31020: *26471 http proxy header: "Location: http://localsite.example.com"
2017/02/07 11:30:41 [debug] 31020#31020: *26471 http proxy header: "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff"
2017/02/07 11:30:41 [debug] 31020#31020: *26471 http proxy header: "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN"
2017/02/07 11:30:41 [debug] 31020#31020: *26471 http proxy header: "X-Request-Id: 69b0b688-bdfb-4be5-ae66-d2ddc71c2f96"
2017/02/07 11:30:41 [debug] 31020#31020: *26471 http proxy header: "X-Runtime: 0.027523"
2017/02/07 11:30:41 [debug] 31020#31020: *26471 http proxy header: "X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block"
2017/02/07 11:30:41 [debug] 31020#31020: *26471 http proxy header: "Connection: close"
2017/02/07 11:30:41 [debug] 31020#31020: *26471 http proxy header done
2017/02/07 11:30:41 [debug] 31020#31020: *26471 posix_memalign: 00007F4038B03F30:4096 @16
2017/02/07 11:30:41 [debug] 31020#31020: *26471 HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 07 Feb 2017 08:30:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Location: http://localsite.example.com
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id: 69b0b688-bdfb-4be5-ae66-d2ddc71c2f96
X-Runtime: 0.027523
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

*UPDATE2*. It looks like a bug in Gitlab. I've tried to turn off my NGINX and enable bundled one, have got the same redirect loop.

Comment: It looks like something is redirecting https -> http. It might be your upstream server doing that. I don't seen anything in the code snippet you've posted above that would do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further updates have brought regression. Version 9.0.5, the bug is here.

However, this can be fixed with Nginx's `proxy_redirect` directive.

One should replace

```
proxy_redirect off;
```

with

```
proxy_redirect http://localsite.example.com https://localsite.example.com/users/sign_in;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was Gitlab Workhorse.

Updating to 8.17 has solved the issue.